# Getting "Cannot deserialize the contract state" when calling Rust init function

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I've been able to run `near dev-deploy` using [near-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/near-shell) for a Rust contract, and then call a function "new" with `near call my-account new '{"param1": "foo"}'`

However, this does not work when I deploy the same contract to my preferred account created with [NEAR Wallet](https://wallet.nearprotocol.com).

The error is:

```
Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'Cannot deserialize the contract state.: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "Unexpected length of input" }',
```

Answer (score 11):

Turns out there is a common problem in the blockchain world when updating a contract at the same account/address.
The solution here was to delete and remake the account.
I used `near-shell` to delete it, then Wallet to recreate it.

On the command line:

```
near delete my-account another-account-getting-the-tokens
```

Then created the account again by visiting:
https://wallet.nearprotocol.com/create/

This cleared the state and I was able to redeploy the contract and run the `init` function "new"

Comment: Awesome! Another solution is to create the sub account with the current as master and then change CONTRACT_NAME in config.js

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled accross the same error in 2021:
`Cannot deserialize the contract state` after making changes to the contract, which has lead me to this stackoverflow question.

I was publishing the contract on testnet by running `yarn dev` which calls `near dev-deploy`.

The solution for me was to generate a new dev-user which can be achieved with passing `-f` as an argument:

```
near dev-deploy -f path/to/contract.wasm
```

You can find this by running dev-deploy --help:

> -f, --init, --force            Create new account for deploy (even if there is one already available). default: false

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document from NEAR: [https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account#:~:text=Each%20NEAR%20account%20can%20only%20hold%201%20smart%20contract](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account#:%7E:text=Each%20NEAR%20account%20can%20only%20hold%201%20smart%20contract)
Each NEAR account can only hold one contract. So you cannot make any update on the existing one. There are some solutions you can try:

- Delete your testnet account then create a new one with the same name as Mike's answer.
- Directly create a new account or a sub-account and deploy the updated contract to the newly created one.